# Compare two EXCEL worksheets and copy similar data onto a third sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote a vba code that would allow me to compare two EXCEL worksheets and paste similar rows to a third sheet. Here it is:

```
'Same data
'If condition met, copy cells
j = 2
    For i = 2 To OLast_row
    IsEqual = False
    For j = 2 To NLast_row
        If OWS.Cells(i, 1).Value = NWS.Cells(j, 1).Value Then
            For Z = 2 To OLast_clmn
                If OWS.Cells(i, Z).Value = NWS.Cells(j, Z).Value Then
                    IsEqual = True
                Else
                    IsEqual = False

                End If
            Next
            If IsEqual = True Then
            cnt = cnt + 1
                CompareWS.Cells(cnt, 1).Value = same
                For D = 1 To OLast_clmn
                    OWS.Cells(i, D).Copy CompareWS.Cells(cnt, D + 1)
                Next

            End If
        Else
    Next
Next
```

Sheet1 being "OWS" declared earlier,
Sheet2 being "NWS" declared earlier,
Sheet2 being "CompareWS" declared earlier

The problem is, this code stops comparing the cells at cell 1 level; for example, if two rows (one in each worksheet) start with the same data, based on this cell the program will consider both rows as identical even if the rest of data don't match.

I suspect "For Z..." condition for not going further than it should, but have no idea how as to how to repair it.

Example of Old data:
[OldData](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuWpJ.png)

Example of New data:
[NewData](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwPRt.png)

Based on these data, ComparedData would look like:
[ComparedData](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTyqA.png)

Hope this will help

Thank you in advance for shedding light on this.

Best.

Comment: Just one quick note to get you started. Your loop starting with `For Z = 2 To OLast_clmn` sets **isEqual** every time through and only based on current column. So it's as if you skipped the every loop iteration except the last one (**OLast_clmn**).

Comment: IYour question would be more clear if you were to include a sample of the data you're starting with, as well as a sample of what the output should look like.  See "[mcve]".

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. I would have pasted examples but seems like  impossible to paste EXCEL sheets in here. But it is simple, **OWS** and **NWS** contain tables having the same format and same number of column(OLast_clmn = NLast_clmn), but not necessarly the same number of rows. **CompareWS** contains the rows contained in **OWS** AND **NWS**, so same number of columns will be copied, but an additional column will be added for the status _same_ for each row, hence, 'OWS.Cells(i, D).Copy CompareWS.Cells(cnt, D + 1)'

Comment: ... you can post screenshots. You can post sample files to file sharing services, ad-free like DropBox, Box or OneDrive, share and post links here. Just use your thinking skills.

Comment: Good idea for the screenshots, thank you teylyn for your thinking skills;) So I posted the screenshot in case this could help you.

Answer (score 0):

Credits to @Mark Balhoff: I would try it this way

```
j = 2
For i = 2 To OLast_row
   IsEqual = False
   For j = 2 To NLast_row
        isequal=true
        For Z = 1 To OLast_clmn
            If OWS.Cells(i, Z).Value <> NWS.Cells(j, Z).Value Then
                IsEqual = False
                exit for
            End If
        Next
        If IsEqual = True Then
              ' copy cells
        End If
   Next
Next
```

Comment: That worked like a charm. Thanks a lot guys @Mark Balhoff & AcsErno, you made my day. Now that I have it in front of me, it seems so obvious.